# Laravel - Additional custom validation only when previous passed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation

I have validation like this:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'parent_id' => 'bail|required|integer|exists:tree_nodes,id',
        'name'      => 'bail|required|max:255',
        'position'  => 'bail|nullable|numeric',
        'path'      => 'bail|nullable|max:255'
    ]);
```

But I need additional custom validation for "path" field based on "parent_id", "name" and "path" fields values and executed only when previous simple validation passed. How to do that?

Comment: `'path'   => 'bail|nullable|max:255|required_with_all:parent_id,name,path'`

Comment: It's not enough because I need also additional custom validator for "path" where (in this custom validator) I need access to "parent_id" and "name" values.

Comment: i think you may check [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)